# How exactly can I produce the output for this?

Tags: c, hex

Question: If the binary equivalent of `5.375` in normalised form is `0100 0000 1010 1100 0000 0000 0000 0000`, what will be the O/P of the following program`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float a = 5.375;
    char * p;
    int i;
    p = (char*)&a;
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        printf("%02X\n",(unsigned char)p[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

This question is in one of my textbooks and has 4 options associated with it. Here, I have several doubts:

1. What exactly does `p` contains? The pointer to?
2. What does `02X` means?
3. Won't the actual `O/P` depend on whether the machine is little endian or big endian?

Anyways, the answer given is: `00 00 AC 40`.

Thanks!

Comment: You will find the answers with a little effort seaching yourself. Read about `printf` format string syntax.

Comment: Alright, I will do that. :)

Comment: Some short info [here](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `char* p;` means that `p` will be a pointer to `char` variable, and then You have:

   ```
   p = (char*)&a;
   ```

   so `p` stores the address (`&`) of variable `a`.
2. `%02X` - convert an unsigned integer into hexadecimal form with capital A-F letters (`X`), always show two "digits" (`2`) with preceding zeros (`0`), more here http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf
3. It should depend, output `00 00 AC 40` is for little endian, `40 AC 00 00` will be for big endian. Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point to see how floating point numbers are stored in memory.